# C# Autogenerated Service Reference can't parse response with ampersand character

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, xml-parsing, service-reference

I'm having trouble with an autogenerated service reference parsing the response that contains ampersand ("&") character (the parsing that's being done automatically under the hood by .NET).

So I'm sending a request to an external service. The request consists of an object that is getting automatically serialized by .NET under the hood. The object contains a string property objectName = "something & something else". Request goes through properly and is received on the other end as is. According to logs the value is also sent back as is. However, upon receiving a response back on our side, the Service Reference fails to parse the "&" bit:

> Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation
>   'addToMonitoring'.    Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.XmlSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader, MessageVersion version, XmlSerializer serializer,
>   MessagePartDescription returnPart, MessagePartDescriptionCollection
>   bodyParts, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.XmlSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription
>   messageDescription, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeReply(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ProxyOperationRuntime.AfterReply(ProxyRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   FinCIS.CIR.SATConsumerBLL.SATMonitoringServiceReference.monitoring_4_03_00_PortType.addToMonitoring(addToMonitoringRequest
>   request)    at
>   FinCIS.CIR.SATConsumerBLL.SATMonitoringServiceReference.monitoring_4_03_00_PortTypeClient.addToMonitoring(SecurityHeaderType
>   Security, requestType2 addToMonitoring1)    at
>   FinCIS.CIR.SATConsumerBLL.ServiceWrapper.SATCompanyMonitoringServiceWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass6.b__5(MonitoringRequestUnit
>   unit)

Inner exception:

> There is an error in XML document (22, 20).

Inner inner exception:

> Unexpected end of file. Following elements are not closed: objectName, monitoringObject, monitoringMaintenanceResponse, Body, Envelope. Line 22, position 20.

Any idea how to fix this?